# I cant remember the name of this book

Tags: story-identification, aliens

So i read this book last year, it’s about a girl who dies trying to save a classmate’s deaf sister from an oncoming truck but dies and gets chosen to fight aliens called daru but find out that they are only following orders and really want peace, and then falls in love with a teammate.